# HTML5 site template phone navigation

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I am using an HTML5 template on my website from HTML5UP.net called ZeroFour. When I preview it locally I can minimise the browser (to phone size) and see the navigation menu on the top left. Once upload to the server however the menu is not visible, although it still works by tapping on the phone or clicking with a mouse.

In every other respect the template works perfectly. Any ideas why this should be?

Comment: Yes, edit line 551 in the template. Seriously, how do you expect anyone should be able to answer, without a code example, a link to the site or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the server not sending the right content type headers for SVGs. I'm posting this to help others who might have a similar problem. More information can be found at http://www.w3.org/services/svg-server/